# Python: Not for Class Instances

Tags: python

In Python, I have the following situation:

I have an instance of a class named my_class_instance.

The code does the following check:

```
if not my_class_instance:
    print ("check was reached")
```

What does `not ...` check in this situation? That `my_class_instance` is referring to `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `not` operator will call `bool` on your instance, then negate the result. So if your class has defined a `__bool__` method, or if you inherit one from a parent class, then that method will be called by `bool`. It will also call `__len__`, if you have one but no `__bool__` (empty containers are falsey). If you don't have one of those methods, your instances will always be truthy.

But even if instances of your class are always truthy, doing `not my_class_instance` might still make sense. The test may just be checking if the variable has an actual instance, rather than a falsey placeholder value like `None`. Such a check should probably be more explicit and use `if my_class_instance is not None` instead of `if not my_class_instance`, but it's not uncommon to write the test that way if you never expect an actual value (rather than `None`) to ever be falsey.